# Unable to restrict the record type by Profile

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to do the record type selection of the Opportunity by the the lightning component like below

Component

```
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectid">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfRecordType}" var="opportunity">                       
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!opportunity}" label="{!opportunity}"  />
  </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

Controller

```
fetchListOfRecordTypes: function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.fetchRecordTypeValues");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        component.set("v.lstOfRecordType", response.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Apex Class

```
@AuraEnabled        
public static List<String> fetchRecordTypeValues(){

    List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordtypes = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();    
    recordtypemap = new Map<Id, String>();
    for(RecordTypeInfo rt : recordtypes){
        if(rt.getName() != 'Master')
            recordtypemap.put(rt.getRecordTypeId(), rt.getName());
    }        
    return recordtypemap.values();
}
```

The issue here is irrespective of the profile type the dropdown shows all the record types in opportunity. I am not sure what I am missing here and how to restrict depending on the dropdown values of record types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a trivial mistake - you must only add the "available" record types:

```
for(RecordTypeInfo rt : recordtypes){
    if(rt.isAvailable() && rt.getName() != 'Master')
        recordtypemap.put(rt.getRecordTypeId(), rt.getName());
}
```

The method "isAvailable" on [RecordTypeInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm) tells you whether the current user has access to the record type. You should probably also test "isActive" too.